# ASP.NET - Redirect image URL to new folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, routes, url-routing

My company is in the process of deprecating our Web Forms projects and using just MVC 3. The default folder for images in MVC 3 is ~/Content/images/.. The problem is that our WebForms was pointing to ~/images/..

We have clients who have direct links to https://www.myurl.com/images/imagename.png and we want it to automatically return the image at https://www.myurl.com/content/images/imagename.png instead.

What is the best route to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an ImageController controller, something like this:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string filename)
    {
        return Redirect("~/Content/images/" + filename);
    }
}
```

Then you'd set up your routing so that the URL `/images/` goes to `ImageController::Index`.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // ...
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ImageRedirects", "images/{filename}", 
        new { controller = "Image", filename = "" });
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked pretty well and will act as an intermediate step until users update their image references. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create HTTP handler and automaticaly redirect to other folder

See this link 
http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=12
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Comment: this is a dead link :(